# Warum gibt es "viel Verkehr" und nicht "vielen Verkehr" auf der Autobahn?

Tags: adjective, inflection

Gemäß [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/viel:A) ist *viel* ein Attributiv und nicht invariabel. Demnach müsste man es beugen. Ist das ein Fehler? Sollte es im Singular unveränderlich sein?

Denn wenn es ein starkes dekliniertes Adjektiv ist, sollte man sagen:

> Es gibt vielen Verkehr auf der Autobahn.

Aber ich habe überall geschaut und sehe nur:

> Es gibt viel Verkehr auf der Autobahn.

Anderes Beispiel:

> Es gibt viel Thunfisch in Japan, das ist mal sicher.

und nicht:

> Es gibt vielen Thunfisch in Japan, das ist mal sicher.

Weitere Beispiele:

> Da ist also auch noch viel Spielraum in den internationalen
>   Verhandlungen.
>
> Es liegt viel Glück in harter Arbeit.

Comment: Kannst du deine Frage bitte ein wenig ausführlicher stellen? Ich weiß nicht genau, was du wissen willst. Bitte gib auch Beispiele, an denen du zeigst was genau dir unklar ist.

Comment: »Es gibt ein**en** Haken an deinen Beispielsätzen«: auf *es gibt* folgt der Akkusativ, nicht der Nominativ. Demnach müsste es *vielen* in beiden Beispielen heißen.

Comment: @Jan I would have corrected it but then the answers wouldn't make sense. I've really messed up here.

Comment: @user5389726598465 The general idea is that answer should not point out grammatical inconsistencies that are not the main focus of the question. Here, the case of *vieler/vielen* is not the core point so it should not have been mentioned in answers but corrected in the question ;) Also it’s not your fault for asking!

Comment: *Viel* is not used like other adjectives, in the singular it behaves more like numbers. Same for *wenig*.

Answer (score 9):

*Viel* ist hier ein [unbestimmtes Zahlwort](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Zahlw%C3%B6rter#Unbestimmte_Zahlw.C3.B6rter). Dass es hier im Singular steht, liegt also an der *Unzählbarkeit* der Substantive. Genauso gut könnte es zum Beispiel heißen

> Es gibt viele Thunfische in Japan.

Dies hätte natürlich eine andere Bedeutung.

Wie du auf *vieler* kommst ist mir nicht klar, vielleicht kannst du das noch spezifizieren. Die Verwendung unbestimmter Zahlwörter ist zumindest eindeutig definiert.

Zur anderen Antwort:

Diese Konstruktion ist etwas ganz anderes. Hier ist *viele* zwar auch ein unbestimmtes Zahlwort, fungiert allerdings als normales Adjektiv zur Spezifikation des Substantives.

> Welches Training? Das *viele* Training.

Comment: Anstatt die zweite Hälfte an die andere Antwort zu richten solltest du sie lieber an den Fragesteller richten. Ich denke, das ist ganz interessant ;)

Answer (score 4):

Ich weiss nicht, ob ich die Frage richtig verstanden habe. Aber eins vorweg: vieler Verkehr ist im Beispielsatz falsch, weil der Verkehr in dem Satz im Akkusativ steht.

Es wäre also durchaus richtig im deutschen zu sagen

> Es gibt vielen Verkehr auf der Autobahn.
>   oder
>   Es gibt vielen Thunfisch in Japan

Trotzdem ist es im deutschen Sprachgebrauch eher unüblich "viel" so anzupassen.

Anders ist es bei viel im Genitiv, da ist die Anpassung definitiv notwendig:

> Die Wirkung vieler Worte ist nicht vorhersehbar
>   oder
>   Das Ansehen vieler grosser Politiker leidet unter der aktuellen Situation

Und auch im Dativ gilt das selbe:

> Grosser Lärm folgt häufig vielem Verkehr

Comment: Grammatikalische (und ähnliche) Fehler, die nicht den Kern der Frage betreffen (wie hier der Kasus) sollten durch Edits korrigiert werden auf mit Kommentaren erklärt werden.

Comment: Die Genitiv-Beispiele sind unglücklich gewählt, weil 'viel' im Plural steht, und da verhält sich 'viel' auch in den anderen Fällen wie andere Adjektive. Beispiele für den Genitiv Singular: Er ist des vielen Lesens müde. Der Lohn vieler Arbeit.

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt durchaus einen flektierten Singular. Ich kenne allerdings nur die schwache Form:

> Das viele Training hat sich ausgezahlt.

Die anderen Formen sind so selten, dass sie für mich ebenso gut nicht existieren könnten.

Comment: Die Wirkung vieler Worte ist manchmal unbeabsichtigt...

Comment: ? "Vieler Worte" ist Genitiv Plural, nicht Singular.

Answer (score -2):

*viel* ist an der Stelle durch *oft* ersetzbar, "auf der Autobahn ist oft Verkehr*, *wird oft gebaut*, etc. Daraus erschließt sich, dass *viel* dabei adverbial gebraucht auf das verb bezogen ist und nicht weiter gebeugt wird. Was das darüber hinaus über *Verkehr sein* aussagt sei dahingestellt.

Comment: *Die Anwohner leiden unter viel Verkehr*, aber nicht *unter oft Verkehr*.