# Why "Viel" and not "Vieles"

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, standard-german

Why it's

> Ich habe viel Geld.

and not

> Ich habe vieles Geld.

Knowing that: Das Geld (neutral)

Comment: Same question, but in German (i.e. no duplicate): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40202/warum-gibt-es-viel-verkehr-und-nicht-vielen-verkehr-auf-der-autobahn

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If »Geld« is neuter, then why not »genuges Geld«?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35793/if-geld-is-neuter-then-why-not-genuges-geld)

Answer (score 10):

*Viel* is an **adverb** (and as such never has endings) meaning "much" and is used with non-countable nouns and singular such as Milch, Zeit, Geld, Arbeit, etc., regardless of gender:

> Ich habe nicht viel Zeit.
>
> Er hat viel Geld.
>
> Es gibt nicht viel Milch im Kühlschrank.
>
> Leider habe ich zu viel Arbeit.

*Viele* is a (plural) **adjective** of indefinite number meaning "many", and as such may have appropriate plural endings (e or en):

> Viele Arbeiter wollen die Firma verlassen.
>
> Mit vielen Kindern ist es schwer zu reisen.

*Vieles* is an **inflected** form from "viel" and used when you drop a noun e.g "Ich weiss vieles, aber nicht alles" means "I know a lot (many things) but not everything".

> Er kann vieles nicht verstehen.
>
> In der damaligen Zeit war vieles anders.
>
> Ich könnte Sie noch vieles fragen.

**viel vs vieles**

*viel* - a lot of work (abstract)

> Ich habe heute viel zu erledigen

"vieles" - a larger number of individual things (more concrete)

> Ich habe heute vieles zu erledigen

Because money can‘t be *counted* (non countable, *"How much money do you have?"* You **can't** say I have 15 money. *"How tall are you?"* You **can** say I'm 1.8m tall -> tall is countable) so you use "viel" of money and not "vieles" ("How is the money?" - You can’t answer "much/a lot of" because it doesn’t describe the money, so it isn't an adjective!)

Comment: Maybe it's instructive to add a countable examples that parallel the uncountable ones,  e.g. _er hat viele Bücher_, _es gibt nicht viele Spinnen im Keller_.

Comment: Grammar aside, money can of course be counted - banks even have machines for that ;)

Comment: It is possible to use "viele Gelder", but this has a different meaning, something like "many funds". Of course you can count money, but in this case the countable unit is not "money" but some currency. ("much money" = "viel Geld" vs. "many dollars" = "viele Dollar")

Comment: Ähnlich wie bei Größe. Größe ist nicht zählbar, aber Einheiten der Skala, in der sie gemessen wird: "Wie groß bist Du?" "1,82 (Eins Komma Acht Zwei)" ist keine gültige Antwort. "1,82m" dagegen schon, denn Meter, auf /100tel genau, lassen sich zählen. "Eins-zweiundachtzig" ist aber doch gängig und also gültig - wohl weil sich aus dem Kontext die fehlende Information (Meter) ergibt.